# Unable to convert varchar to datetime

Tags: t-sql

Unfortunately, I came across a database which stores date as varchar, instead of datetime.
It stores MULTIPLE date formats (eg xx/yy/zzzz, xx/yy/zz, x/y/zzzz etc). Eventually, I wish to convert them all to xx/yy/zzzz with the ones I can.

I am trying to do some data cleansing and trying out some SELECT statements to see what can be converted to what.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT MyDate, CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME) AS MyDate_Mod FROM MyTable
WHERE ISDATE(MyDate) <> 0 AND MyDate NOT LIKE '__/__/____'
```

That seems to execute OK.

Next goal is to find dates with year greater than 2000 because some CAST of 2 digit year (eg xx/yy/zz) automatically converts to 20zz instead of 19zz.
Anyway so I updated the SELECT to:

```
SELECT MyDate, CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME) AS MyDate_Mod FROM MyTable
WHERE ISDATE(MyDate) <> 0 AND MyDate NOT LIKE '__/__/____' AND YEAR(CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME)) >= 2000
```

Running above statement failed with conversion issue.

Maybe I thought the order of execution mattered as CAST in WHERE statement might have executed before ISDATE <> 0.

Modified the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT MyDate, CAST(MyDate AS DATETIME) AS MyDate_Mod FROM MyTable
    WHERE ISDATE(MyDate) <> 0 AND MyDate NOT LIKE '__/__/____') AS Sub
WHERE YEAR(Sub.MyDate_Mod) >= 2000
```

This also failed.

Can someone explain to me why it is failing, if it is looking for a valid ISDATE(MyDate)?

Answer (score 1):

Still not allowed to comment yet (but treat this as one). For that third query did you try something like:

```
SELECT Top 10 Sub.*, Datepart(year,Sub.MyDate_Mod)
FROM 
    (SELECT MyDate, CAST(MyDate AS DateTime) AS MyDate_Mod
     FROM MyTable
     WHERE ISDATE(MyDate) <> 0 AND MyDate NOT LIKE '__/__/____') AS Sub
```

This would just be to see if you get any results or if it is always throwing an error. If it works then try to move it to the WHERE clause.

Comment: I tried that, and it works. However, if I put the Datepart() into WHERE clause, it fails with the same Conversion error. Weird!!!

Comment: Curious again, if you nest that select statement as well so you are simply doing a select * from... where alias_for_date_part >= 2000 will it work? Not that it is the cleanest code, but that is weird.

Comment: My assumption is that the SQL Execution planner pulls the statement apart and re-orders it to an optimum level (to its view) and somehow executes ISDATE later.